# Separate float number in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, delimiter, separator

I would like to read my text file in; however, the there is no clear deliminator in this data.
I would like to use sep=' .' ; this is not quite right to get correct format.
ex. df = pd.read_table('data.txt', header = None, sep =' .'). Could you give me some heads-up, the correct separator for this case? Thank you!

```
cont1                7.6327.6957.5692.5951.3051.5920.8740.6810.1920.393
cont2                7.5947.6577.5302.3831.4561.5820.8610.6860.2860.340
cont3                7.5557.6237.4872.3701.3511.5900.8680.6830.2840.408
cont4                7.4957.5937.3982.4261.3431.6440.9140.6770.3530.138
cont5                7.4877.5707.4052.3201.4201.5490.9270.6600.2560.357
cont6                7.4417.4987.3842.4481.3611.4880.8780.6380.3330.295
```

Comment: What is expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas.read_fwf()`, e.g.:

```
In []:
from io import StringIO

s = '''cont1                7.6327.6957.5692.5951.3051.5920.8740.6810.1920.393
cont2                7.5947.6577.5302.3831.4561.5820.8610.6860.2860.340
cont3                7.5557.6237.4872.3701.3511.5900.8680.6830.2840.408
cont4                7.4957.5937.3982.4261.3431.6440.9140.6770.3530.138
cont5                7.4877.5707.4052.3201.4201.5490.9270.6600.2560.357
cont6                7.4417.4987.3842.4481.3611.4880.8780.6380.3330.295'''

pd.read_fwf(StringIO(s), header=None, widths=[21, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5])

Out[]:
      0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      10
0  cont1  7.632  7.695  7.569  2.595  1.305  1.592  0.874  0.681  0.192  0.393
1  cont2  7.594  7.657  7.530  2.383  1.456  1.582  0.861  0.686  0.286  0.340
2  cont3  7.555  7.623  7.487  2.370  1.351  1.590  0.868  0.683  0.284  0.408
3  cont4  7.495  7.593  7.398  2.426  1.343  1.644  0.914  0.677  0.353  0.138
4  cont5  7.487  7.570  7.405  2.320  1.420  1.549  0.927  0.660  0.256  0.357
5  cont6  7.441  7.498  7.384  2.448  1.361  1.488  0.878  0.638  0.333  0.295
```